# mac osx 10.9, Automatically connect to network drive on startup, wake up

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, network-drive

I have a shared folder in the Ubuntu 13.10 server.  I can connect to this shared folder from my mac os using "connect to server"

```
smb://ubuntunas/download
```

I dont want to do it manually everytime. is it possible to connect to it at startup

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a question about operating system functionality and is not a programming question as defined in the [help] guidelines. It is better suited for [apple.se] or [su] instead.

Comment: Here is the same question in Super User: http://superuser.com/questions/130787/permanently-map-a-network-drive-on-mac-os-x-leopard

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to the Apple menu and System Preferences. Select the "Users" tab and select your own user. Drag the share to your Startup Items.